# Is forcing I2C communication safe?

Tags: linux, embedded, arm, i2c

For a project I'm working on I have to talk to a multi-function chip via I2C. I can do this from linux user-space via the I2C /dev/i2c-1 interface.

However, It seems that a driver is talking to the same chip at the same time. This results in my I2C_SLAVE accesses to fail with An errno-value of EBUSY. Well - I can override this via the ioctl I2C_SLAVE_FORCE. I tried it, and it works. My commands reach the chip.

Question: Is it safe to do this? I know for sure that the address-ranges that I write are never accessed by any kernel-driver. However, I am not sure if forcing I2C communication that way may confuse some internal state-machine or so.(I'm not *that* into I2C, I just use it...)

For reference, the hardware facts:

```
 OS:           Linux
 Architecture: TI OMAP3 3530
 I2C-Chip:     TWL4030 (does power, audio, usb and lots of other things..)
```

Comment: Did you try asking this question on http://chiphacker.com ? It's an SO-like site but for electronics (although not nearly as active as SO itself).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know that particular chip, but often you have commands that require a sequence of writes, first to one address to set a certain mode, then you read or write another address -- where the function of the second address changes based on what you wrote to the first one. So if the driver is in the middle of one of those operations, and you interrupt it (or vice versa), you have a race condition that will be difficult to debug. For a reliable solution, you better communicate through the chip's driver...

Comment: How do we deal with this problem if we are writing chip driver. From my understanding, I am using I2C_SLAVE and I2C_SLAVE_FORCE in my chip's driver code. So is it advisable to use I2C_SLAVE_FORCE in chip's driver code ?

Answer (score 2):

I mostly agree with @Wim. But I would like to add that this can definitely cause irreversible problems, or destruction, depending on the device.

I know of a Gyroscope (L3GD20) that requires that you don't write to certain locations.  The way that the chip is setup, these locations contain manufacturer's settings which determine how the device functions and performs.

This may seem like an easy problem to avoid, but if you think about how I2C works, all of the bytes are passed one bit at a time.  If you interrupt in the middle of the transmission of another byte, results can not only be truly unpredictable, but they can also increase the risk of permanent damage exponentially.  This is, of course, entirely up to the chip on how to handle the problem.

Since microcontrollers tend to operate at speeds much faster than the bus speeds allowed on I2C, and since the bus speeds themselves are dynamic based on the speeds at which devices process the information, the best bet is to insert pauses or loops between transmissions that wait for things to finish.  If you have to, you can even insert a timeout.  If these pauses aren't working, then something is wrong with the implementation.